# Unable to upgrade pip, SSL errors

Tags: python, pip

I'm running this version of pip:

> pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)

Python 3.5.5, OpenSSL 1.0.2o 27 Mar 2018

I'm upgrading pip manually via `python get-pip.py`.

Trying to upgrade gives me:

```
# python3.5 -V
Python 3.5.5
# python3.5 get-pip.py
Collecting pip
/tmp/tmp9_42ubbb/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:339: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:719)'),)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:719)'),)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:719)'),)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:719)'),)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:719)'),)': /simple/pip/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:719)'),)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:719)'),)) - skipping
```

What am I missing here? My openssl should be fairly up-to-date.

In addition, why would I be getting `extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this.` on Python 3.5.5?

Comment: Have you checked the info here? https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5226

Comment: @souldeux Yes, that is what I'm trying. Manually updating, and that is the error I'm getting from manually updating.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru That seems to refer to pip commands, I'm running Python command to execute get-pip.py

Comment: @Zeno I missed that part, my bad.